# Copying files from the specified hosts to others in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have three hosts available in my inventory file

```
[controller]
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

i have a variable in group_var folder which specifies the master node

```
master=1.1.1.1
```

sql.conf is available in my home directory (/home/ubuntu/sql.conf) of all 3 controller hosts.

Now, i need to copy the file (test.txt) from master to others . Is there any way in ansible to copy the files from one specific server to others.

i am trying like this but couldnt achieve though.

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: copy files
      local_action: command rsync -a /home/ubuntu/test.txt {{ master }}:///home/ubuntu/test.txt
```

Comment: "...but couldnt achieve though".  What happened?  Were there error messages?  Where are you running Ansible? You're running rsync from a *local* action; I thought `test.txt` was on the master.  Your rsync command appears to be trying to copy `test.txt` from your local host *to* the master server.

Comment: test.txt file exists in all 3 nodes. i want to copy it from master to other 2 nodes. Please ignore what i tried. am not sure whether it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the `fetch` module to copy the file from the master node to your local node, and then use the `copy` module normally to distribute that file to other nodes.  Something like:

```
- hosts: master
  tasks:
    - fetch: 
        src: /path/to/myfile.txt
        dest: tmp/

- hosts: all:!master
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: tmp/master/myfile.txt
        dest: /path/to/myfile.txt
```